# Using a spatial database to find polygons that contain a point

Tags: mongodb, spatial, spatial-query, spatial-index, database

I'm using MongoDB to store spatial records.  Some records are polygons, and others are points.  Data is being continually inserted.

I need to be able to access all records whose polygon contains a point.  Mongo's spatial queries allow finding all points within a polygon, but not all polygons that contain a point.  Is there a good way to do this in MongoDB another database system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to run this query at present -- unless you're willing to simplify the application (i.e., assume all polygons are circles of a particular radius [or small set of radii]).

There's an open ticket for the functionality you described:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2874

Comment: Thanks.  This would be a great thing for mongodb.  I suppose I may have to switch to a different DB until this is added.